# AMPScript for removing an email address / subscriber from a list?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, list

Is there any way to "remove" an email address / subscriber from a list by AMPScript?

If yes, could you please provide the AMPScript?

I am NOT looking to change the subscriber status. I need to remove the subscriber from a specific list on a button click event on a microsite.

NOT looking for an API solution.

Comment: "Write this code for me" type questions aren't very popular around here.  I'd suggest posting what code you've tried -- even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use API AmpScript to delete the subscriber from a specific list. You just need to change the list id (i.e. 12345) and pass in the mentioned code.

```
%%[
SET @Subscriber=CreateObject("Subscriber")
    SetObjectProperty(@Subscriber,"SubscriberKey","test@gmail.com")
    SetObjectProperty(@Subscriber,"EmailAddress","test@gmail.com")

SET @list=CreateObject("SubscriberList")
    SetObjectProperty(@list,"ID","12345") 
    AddObjectArrayItem(@Subscriber,"Lists",@list)
SET @Status = InvokeDelete(@Subscriber,@status_msg,@Update_err) 
]%%

%%=v(@Status)=%%
```

**Output:** OK